# How to customize (add/remove folders/directories) the "Places" menu of Ubuntu 13.04 "Files" application?

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, 13.04, places

I can't seem to find a way to customize (add/remove folders/directories) the "Places" menu in the most recent "Files" application of Ubuntu 13.04. The procedures used with "Nautilus" in the previous versions of Ubuntu (bookmarking or drag&drop) don't seem to work anymore.

Does anybody have a clue on how to do that?

Comment: This answer is wrong: it creates a bookmark in the Bookmark section but not, as the questioner (and I) want, in the Places section.

Comment: You are right, I removed the answer as accepted

Comment: Yeah I know - I don't know why nautilus has that peculiar distinction between the two. The unity quicklist doesn't. I've not found a way to do exactly what was asked for - maybe there is a way, but I don't know it :-)

Answer (score 35):

First of all, open a nautilus window to the directory you wish to add. Then click the small cog icon in the top right of the nautilus window and click the 'Bookmark this location' entry. It will be added to the "Bookmarks" section of the sidebar.

[image: Add a nautilus bookmark in Ubuntu 13.04]

Comment: This button is not available in 12.04. How can I accomplish the same thing here?

Comment: And for @Krige's other question... to remove a bookmark just right click on it and chose "Remove".

Comment: But this does not answer exactly what asked for: It adds folders in **Bookmark** section of sidebar, not in **Places** section!

Comment: @hobs: This way only works for removing **Bookmark** s, but how to remove folders from **Places** section?

Comment: If the gear button/icon is not available (in newer versions) you can use the shortcut ```Ctrl+D``` to on a folder you're in and it'll be added to the Bookmarks sections

Answer (score 33):

I met the same problem and I found the following solution:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

remove the list you do not want.
However, once you login again, it will reset, so -->

```
echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf
```

Reference: http://jamesmcminn.com/2012/12/removing-entries-from-nautilus-3-6-places/

Alternatively, one may also solve everything by directly modifying Sysadmins file in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`, for more details refer to:
[Functions of xdg-user-dirs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29671/functions-of-xdg-user-dirs)

Comment: It seems that `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` is not related to **Nautilus Places**, because it contains only constants that do not matches exactly folders listed in **Places** section.

Comment: After upgrading from 12.10, my nautilus Places showed Desktop for both the desktop and the downloads.  Editing ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs as indicated in this answer I was able to correct this.

Comment: @PHPLearner even though they don't match, modifying still works (not sure why).  I followed the instructions and places updated when I logged out and logged back in.

Comment: This works. If you also want to remove the folders from the home directory, edit user-dirs.defaults, or make a copy of it in .config and edit there (for your local user).

Comment: why does Ubuntu keep gedit as the default editor instead of Scite?

Answer (score 23):

I just upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and I was suprised that my bookmarks are all gone in Nautilus!

I found that old `~/.gtk-bookmarks` file has been replaced with `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` file. So all I had to do was copy / paste old bookmarks to new file. The syntax is the same.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 14):

For the time being use: `Ctrl+D`

Adding bookmarks via the menu seems to be broken right now. The help says to add a new bookmark, do:

> Open the folder (or location) that you want to bookmark.
>
> Click Bookmarks ▸ Add Bookmark.

The only entry I see in the menu is `Files` though, I can select `Bookmarks` there, but then only have the option to delete existing bookmarks.

Comment: I was looking for an option in the global menu and didn't even see the buttons on the right. So this is not broken, but obviously not obvious.

Comment: It took me longer than it should have too - it really isn't obvious at all. Bad UI in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and removing `Pirtures/Music/Videos` seems to remove them from the Places as well.

I am not sure if that has any other implications though, but it works.

Its not perfect but it makes the Places menu a little less annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, this works for me. My file manager is Nautilus.

1. Open nautilus as root

   ```
   sudo -H nautilus &>/dev/null
   ```
2. Open the folder you want to add as bookmark.

   [image: Open the folder you want to add as bookmark]
3. Open *Bookmarks* in the top menu bar -> click *Bookmark this Location*.

   [image: Open **Bookmarks** in the top menu bar -> click **Bookmark this Location**]