# How to move downloads folder from bookmarks to places?

Tags: nautilus, downloads, places

I cant move the downloads folder from bookmarks to places in 14.04. I did some mistakes and first I lost the downloads folder. Now I cant move it into the places.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 7):

Edit file  `/your_home_directory/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. File contents should be below

```
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
```

You can change the path of default directories. If you have missed some directory, check if that is present in this file.

Comment: But I can't add a directory, right? It has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in
[How to customize (add/remove folders/directories) the "Places" menu of Ubuntu 13.04 "Files" application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285313/how-to-customize-add-remove-folders-directories-the-places-menu-of-ubuntu-13)
and as indicated there, you might need to edit `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` on top of `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`