# Desktop icon disappear in nautilus sidebar after upgrade

Tags: nautilus

I just did a freshinstall of Ubuntu 22.04.1. When I used Nautilus after installation the "Desktop" folder was visible in the sidebar, however after the first upgrade the folder disappeared.

Same, if Ubuntu on Xorg is started, the folder reappears...

ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't appear either with standard settings. It isn't supposed to appear.

Comment: Yes, the the answer above explains why.

Comment: According with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192026/why-doesnt-xdg-desktop-dir-directory-appear-in-sidebar-of-nautilus-files is a problem of "consistency". Well, this kind of consistency is not functional. It's nice to have a shortcut to Desktop in the file explorer. I added a Desktop icon as bookmark, but in my opinion this is a sloppy solution.

Comment: Here's a history lesson: the desktop was never intended to save files or anything else therefore there never was a necessity to access it as regular folder. That it was possible in *some* (and only some) OSes with GUI was an unintended consequence, a side effect, of having the file manager also managing the desktop itself. Until recently this was (and in some cases still is) the situation with many Linux desktop environments. It no longer happens with Gnome. You're free to try others.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's always nice to learn new things.
One question, I just did a test booting the laptop from a USB Flash and selecting the option to try Ubuntu (22.04). Well, when you open Nautilus, the Desktop icon appears in the Nautilus sidebar. I don't understand why it disappears in the installed version.

Comment: Ok. If I start a session using Xorg (Ubuntu on Xorg option) the desktop icon appears in the left side panel as usual. But this do not happend if is start a normal session.